# Don't understand error messages for numeric_std to_unsigned function call, selected signal assignment

Tags: vhdl

I designed a simple shifter but I got an error, I applied different lots of things to solve, then it hasn't been fixed.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
--use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
--use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;


entity shifter is
    Port ( inp          : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
           shift_cntrl  : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0);
           shift_out    : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0));
end shifter;

architecture Behavioral of shifter is
begin
process(shift_cntrl, inp) begin
    with shift_cntrl select  
       shift_out <= STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(to_unsigned(inp, shift_out'LENGTH) sll 4) when "01", 
                    STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(to_unsigned(inp, shift_out'LENGTH) sll 8) when "10",  
                    inp when others;
                    
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

VHDL error messages:

```
[Synth 8-2778] type error near inp ; expected type natural [shifter.vhd:18]
[Synth 8-2778] type error near inp ; expected type natural [shifter.vhd:19]
[Synth 8-2757] this construct is only supported in VHDL 1076-2008 [shifter.vhd:20]
```

Comment: Please, never show text with images. They are not searchable, not copy-paste-able and much heavier than needed. Copy-paste the text in your question and [format it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), instead.

Answer (score 0):

`with..select` is only supported inside a process when the file mode is set to VHDL 2008. Either set the file mode in Vivado to 2008 or simply remove the process around the `with..select` statement as it is not needed.

In addition, there is no function `to_unsigned` for a `std_logic_vector`. Because it is a similar type, you can do a type conversion:

```vhdl
STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(unsigned(inp) sll 4);
```